# Loop through class objects - Visual basic

Tags: vb.net, class, loops, object

How can i loop through all objects of a class in vb.net, instead of doing as below. I want to init my class objects in the code (it's an example), and then make a for each loop through them all instead of the code in the bottom.

```
    'Angiv 1. saldo, 2. Navn, 3. CPR nummer, 4. pinkode
Dim Kunde1 As New Kunde(1010, "Mads Peter Petersen", "010190-0000", 1111)
Dim Kunde2 As New Kunde(2020, "John Pedersen", "010190-0001", 2222)
Dim Kunde3 As New Kunde(3030, "Flemming Farsø", "010190-0002", 3333)
Dim Kunde4 As New Kunde(4040, "Didrich Rich", "010190-0003", 4444)
Dim Kunde5 As New Kunde(5050, "Tobias Larsen", "010190-0004", 5555)
Dim aktivKunde As Kunde


Private Sub Main()
    btn100.Enabled = False
    btn200.Enabled = False
    btn500.Enabled = False
    btn1000.Enabled = False
    btnGodkend.Enabled = False
    btnVisbevaegelser.Enabled = False
End Sub


Private Sub btnTjek_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTjek.Click


    If Kunde1.Tjek(CInt(txtPinkode.Text), CInt(txtCpr.Text.Substring(txtCpr.Text.Length - 4))) Then
        txtSaldo.Text = Kunde1.Saldo
        txtNavn.Text = Kunde1.Navn
        aktivKunde = Kunde1
        AktiverKnapper()


    ElseIf Kunde2.Tjek(CInt(txtPinkode.Text), CInt(txtCpr.Text.Substring(txtCpr.Text.Length - 4))) Then
        txtSaldo.Text = Kunde2.Saldo
        txtNavn.Text = Kunde2.Navn
        aktivKunde = Kunde2
        AktiverKnapper()


    ElseIf Kunde3.Tjek(CInt(txtPinkode.Text), CInt(txtCpr.Text.Substring(txtCpr.Text.Length - 4))) Then
        txtSaldo.Text = Kunde3.Saldo
        txtNavn.Text = Kunde3.Navn
        aktivKunde = Kunde3
        AktiverKnapper()


    ElseIf Kunde4.Tjek(CInt(txtPinkode.Text), CInt(txtCpr.Text.Substring(txtCpr.Text.Length - 4))) Then
        txtSaldo.Text = Kunde4.Saldo
        txtNavn.Text = Kunde4.Navn
        aktivKunde = Kunde4
        AktiverKnapper()


    ElseIf Kunde5.Tjek(CInt(txtPinkode.Text), CInt(txtCpr.Text.Substring(txtCpr.Text.Length - 4))) Then
        txtSaldo.Text = Kunde5.Saldo
        txtNavn.Text = Kunde5.Navn
        aktivKunde = Kunde5
        AktiverKnapper()

    Else : MessageBox.Show("Der var desværre ingen kunder med dette CPR-nummer & pinkode", "Forkert pinkode eller CPR-nummer")
    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing is to use a collection/List:

```
' declare the list var AND create an instance of it (these are objects)
Private myKunde As New List(of Kunde)

 ...
myKunde.Add(New Kunde(1010, "Mads Peter Petersen", "010190-0000", 1111))
myKunde.Add(New Kunde(2020, "John Pedersen", "010190-0001", 2222))
... etc
```

To loop:

```
For Each k As Kunde In myKunde 
   Console.WriteLine(k.Name)           ' ??
Next
```

To reference a specific one:

```
Console.WriteLine(myKunde(1).Name)   
' remove Kunde John:
myKunde.RemoveAt(1)

' start over:
myKunde.Clear
```

Display *entire* contents of the list in a ListBox:

```
lbKunde.DataSource = myKunde
```

If Kunde overrides `ToString()`, that is what will display for each item.

They are like an array except you do not have to know how big to make it ahead of time, just add items to it. The `List(of T)` has oodles of other methods such as `Sort` and `Reverse` and you can also use extension methods on it and query the collection.

The button click (cant translate what it says) can be something like:

```
Sub btnClick(....
  Dim Kindex As Integer

  ' this might be able to be reduced more, I dont know what they are
  ' a LISTBOX would certainly get rid of it
  If Kunde1.Tjek Then
      Kindex = 1
  ElseIf Kunde2.Tjek
      Kindex = 2
  ...

  DisplayKunde(KIndex)
  ...

Private Sub DisplayKinde(ndx As integer)
    ' display desired Kunde to txt controls
    txtBox1.Text = myKunde(ndx).Name      ' ? no idea whats in Kinde
    txtBox2.Text = myKunde(ndx).Foo
    txtBox3.Text = myKunde(ndx).Bar
    ...
End Sub
```

Comment: In my for each loop, i cant write ".. In myKunde" ? It says that it is not declared?

Comment: the very first line of code declares **and** creates an instance; if this is code in a form, make sure it is outside any SUB

Comment: Can't i just do like this? But it dont work as before?
       For Each kundeNavn As Kunde In kundeListe
            If kundeNavn.Tjek(CInt(txtPinkode.Text), CInt(txtCpr.Text.Substring(txtCpr.Text.Length - 4))) Then
                txtSaldo.Text = kundeNavn.Saldo
                txtNavn.Text = kundeNavn.Navn
                aktivKunde = kundeNavn
                AktiverKnapper()

            Else : MessageBox.Show("Der var desværre ingen kunder med dette CPR-nummer & pinkode", "Forkert pinkode eller CPR-nummer")
            End If

Comment: Sorry, I cant read/understand any of that, so I cant tell what you are trying to do.  it doesnt look like you are using the indexer though.  `Navn` seems to be a property tjhough, so `For each k As Kunde in myKundeList // If k.Navn ...` is probably more what you want

Comment: Update: it works if i put the Kundeliste.Add.... in the same sub as the for each loop - how come? :) P.s Thanks for your help!!

Comment: well you have to add the items to the list *before* you try to iterate the list, it doesnt have to be the same sub, just filled beforehand

Comment: But if i only add them in the Sub Main() , it does not work? Weird..... Not even an error message.

Comment: No, it the code needs to add them before you use them is all.

Comment: So i have to place them inside the Button_click? Will they not be added everytime i use that button then?

Comment: you can fill the list in Form Load or Sub Main or elesewhere as long as that code runs before the user can click a button which uses the list...there could even be a button to fill the list.

Comment: If i fill the list within the Click button, it works fine. But if i fill it in the Form Load og Sub - it runs, but do not work...

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how you implemented it.  It sounds like the scope of the list is local and not module level.  Declare it OUTSIDE any sub or function, as I said.

Comment: Last look please: http://www.codeshare.io/hMGOW It it this code that does not work. ONLY if i place the Add's within the click button. Or call a sub that adds them within that.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the For/Each.  Hold the mouse over `kundeListe` - it will display the list for you to see it is all there.  After the For/Each line executes, view `kundeNavn` it should have the props for the first one added.  There is no voodoo - all five should be there.  I dont know what the rest of the code does, but it may be failing there (substring on an empty TextBox will fail).

Comment: It says that there are no children available, when it is declared within the Main sub. Weird. - But thanks for your help dude :-)